# Eclipse Formatter following Java code convention?

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

Eclipse comes up with built in Code Style > Code Formatter and Code Style > clean up . But i am not sure if they have done some modifications
on top of Oracle defined java coding convention or not ?

Can i get the formatter/cleanup xmls as per oracle defined java coding convention . I tried to Google it but could not spot any?

Comment: You need to learn how to google my friend : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf

Comment: I said i could not find for matter following the coding convention. I could not find that in the link you mentioned also. Obviously i could spot the java coding conventions.

Comment: The default formatter provided by eclipse follows these conventions. That's the point I was trying to make.

Comment: There are 2 default formatters called `Eclipse` and `Java` IIRC. The latter is the one you want.

Comment: I think you are talking about Java Conventions[built in] option present in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you exactly asking for, because i didn't understand your Question

If you mean formatting, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ F

For code formatting in eclipse <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ A then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ I

May this info helpful to you :)